# Searching an element by multiple criterias?

Tags: c++, data-structures

The code below creates a vector of Orders:

```
#include <vector>

struct Order
{
    int uniqueId;
    double price;
    int time;
};

using V = std::vector<Order>;

int main()
{  
    V v { {1, 3.0, 5}, {2, 5.0, 7}, {3, 2.0, 1}};
    
    return 0;
}
```

What additional data structure should I create to be able by given `time` and `price` find an order with minimal `std::tie(order.price, order.time)` satisfying the criteria `order.time >= time && order.price >= price` with O(log2 N) complexity?

If we found multiple orders we choose the order with minimal `uniqueId` that is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227738/discussion-on-question-by-dmitriano-searching-an-element-by-multiple-criterias).

Answer (score 1):

I think a **binary search tree** would be perfect for the task, since operations on it as access, search, insert, delete imply time complexity of `log(n)`, where `n` is the size of data.

In C++ you can use the `std::set` container, which is internally structured as a binary search tree with default `operator<` ordering (from smallest to largest item). Given that `uniqueId` fields inside `Order` items are guaranteed different from one other, `std::set` is the choice here, over `std::multiset`.

Thus, given a threshold `K = (price, time)`, use of the  `std::set::lower_bound` member function will yield the first element in the `set` equal or bigger than that threshold:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

using std::cout;      using std::endl;
using std::set;       using std::lower_bound;
using std::make_tuple;

struct Order
{
    int uniqueId;
    double price;
    int time;
};

struct Compare {
  bool operator() (const Order& lhs, const Order& rhs) const
  {auto l_tuple = make_tuple(lhs.price, lhs.time, lhs.uniqueId);
   auto r_tuple = make_tuple(rhs.price, rhs.time, rhs.uniqueId);
   return l_tuple < r_tuple;}
};

using S = set<Order, Compare>;

int main()
{
    // define set ordered, respectively, by prices, time, uniqueId
    S my_set({ {1, 3.0, 5}, {2, 5.0, 7}, {3, 2.0, 1} });
    Order K = {0, 2.5, 1};   // example of threshold for price and time
    auto next_K = my_set.lower_bound(K); // iterator

    cout << "Minimal order with price at least = " << K.price << " and time at least = "
         << K.time << " has ID: " << next_K->uniqueId << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Now code sorts `Order` items, respectively, for `price`, `time`, and `uniqueId`, then outputs the lowest ranked `Order` with `(price, time) >= K`, where `K` is a threshold pair of values of `price` and `time`.

In case there are multiple `Order` items that rank lowest with identical `(price, time)` combination, the program will pick the `Order` with lower `uniqueId` among them.

See compiled result at https://wandbox.org/permlink/egZFscfbrrJtciF4 .

Complexity is `log(n)` of `std::set::lower_bound`, not counting cost of construction of the `set<Order, Compare>`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik you get different elements as the result of two searches, right?

Comment: @Thomas The item with lower `price` among those with `price >= 2.5` and with lowest `time` but bigger than `1` has indeed `uniqueId = 1`. Your critique of my code time complexity is more centred, I create one `set` too many, if there were a way to modify the compare function in the same `set`, that would be spot on, because I would not need to create a whole new `set` for each comparison.

Comment: @Thomas I use `time=1, price= 2.5` as thresholds for my example, so different result.

Comment: @Thomas Using constraint `time=1, price=2.5`, any of the three new orders you have input is fine. The actual order with lowest `uniqueId` is in fact item 1. I could add another check on min `uniqueId`, but I'd rather solve the issue of having more than 1 `set` constructed. If there was just the initial `set` and no other copy construction involved, this solution would have indeed achieved complexity `log(n)`.

Comment: @Thomas in the body of the question OP does not prioritise between `time` and `price`, he just mandates to get rid of all values less than the thresholds in both. What he says  in the comments is another matter entirely... Your other sarcastic remark about the time complexity of this answer may be appropriate, if in fact there effectively were no way to unbind the `comparePrice` functor from the `set`, and assign another fucntor to it, `compareTime`. Some other user may know more about this, stop by and propose a solution, you never know.

Comment: @Thomas `std::tie` was not mentioned in the first version of the question, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's a good solution. Using a `std::set` with appropriate compare function is better than using a sorted `std::vector` I think.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, even though this solution is still stifled by the fact that a lambda function cannot be used inside the `std::set` for `Compare` purposes, and by the cost of building the `std::set` itself, which is actually linearithmic.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's impossible without sorting at least once.